# Java String to byte

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I have a String like this in my Java code.

```
String my = "16 12 12 -119 102 105 -110 52 -89 80 -122 -68 114 20 -92 -28 -121 38 113 61"
```

the values separated by " " is integer ( you can see it ).

I can convert the integers to a int array, but I need to convert the `int` values to a `byte` array. The value represented by each integer is a byte value.

PS.

```
String aa[] = U.split(" ");
byte bb[] = new byte[aa.length];

for(int q=0;q<aa.length;q++){
  int v = Integer.parseInt(aa[q]);

  bb[q] = ???????????????????--the code I need to convert the int to a byte

}
```

Comment: Well how are you converting the values to an `int` array? Chances are you could skip that and convert them straight to bytes. Please show your code so far. (If you *do* need to convert the `int[]` to `byte[]`, you can just create a new array and convert each value in turn, with a `for` loop. Again - what have you tried?

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far.

Comment: String string_as_int[] = U.split(" ");
using a for loop and Integer.parseInt();
I converted them to a int array...

Comment: So when you can use the `java.lang.Integer`-class why not look at `java.lang.Byte` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
String[] parts = my.split(" ");
byte[] bytes = new byte[parts.length];

for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(parts[i]);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

> [16, 12, 12, -119, 102, 105, -110, 52, -89, 80, -122, -68, 114, 20, -92, -28, -121, 38, 113, 61]

Be sure to look over the API for the `Byte` class, notably [`Byte.parseByte()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte(java.lang.String)).

Comment: No prob, homes.  Remember each of the primitive types has an associated class with helpful utilities (`Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, etc.).  Additionally, the Guava library provides several more useful [primitive utilities](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You apparently can do most of my answer except for one line. You can just replace this line:

```
int v = Integer.parseInt(aa[q]);
```

with this (there's no need to make it an `int` first, so just skip it and go right to the `byte`):

```
bb[q] = Byte.parseByte(aa[q]);
```

Or you could just cast the `int` you created to a `byte`, like this:

```
int v = Integer.parseInt(aa[q]);
bb[q] = (byte)v;
```

---

The first thing you do is convert that single `String` into an array of `String`s by using the [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, like this:

```
String[] strArray = my.split(" "); // split by the spaces
```

Then, create a byte array, which will be the same length as the string array:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[strArray.length];
```

Then iterate over the String array and add each element of the `String` array to the `byte` array. Each time you add a number, you have to parse it to a `byte` from a `String`, using the [`Byte#parseByte(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte(java.lang.String)) method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
    byteArray[i] = Byte.parseByte(strArray[i]);
}
```

And then you should have your byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and parse each individual String token as `Byte` :-

```
String my = "16 12 12 -119 102 105 -110 52 -89 80 -122 -68 114 20 -92 -28 -121 38 113 61";
String [] ints = my.split (" ");
byte[] bArr=new byte[ints.length];

for(int i=0;i<ints.length;i++){

  bArr[i]=Byte.parseByte(ints[i]);
  System.out.println(bArr[i]);
}
```